# how can I make my JWT tokens browser specific to prevent access from stolen tokens?

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, authentication, jwt, session-cookies

I am using JWT and Spring security for user authentication and session management. It is working perfectly fine but I am worried what would I do if JWT will be compromised means I will use JWT of an user from some other system then I will able to access his/her previlages because JWT is not browser specific.
That's why, I want to make my JWT browser specific so that, now onw will able to login from same JWT using another machine.

I searched different way and I found one solution i.e. using cookies, we can differenciate the client browser but I don't think, it will be wise to use session cookies with JWT.

So, please guide me through this, how can I make JWT browser specific?

Comment: You can make JWT with username and password and clientIP and in every request from front you can decode token in backend and check it with request client IP

Comment: Thanks for reply. But this will fail if user is connected with wifi because IP will change automatically and this will make user unauthorised any time between his session that's why, I am looking browser specific solution.

Comment: browser specific can be simulated

Comment: then, please guide me. What will be the best solution for the same?

Comment: And what if will use cookies along with JWT that will make JWT browser specific?

Comment: any thing except hardware info can be simulate

Comment: @BabakYaghoobi What will you say about using cookies with JWT? I think this approach will be better than using hardware information.

Comment: can be good with validate https

Comment: Ok, thanks for help. If you don't mind, I have one more query i.e. why do we use JWT if it is not that much safe because now in my case I will need to use cookies as well and I can get session management functionalities using cookies only. So, what is the purpose of using JWT?

Comment: cookie does not have security alone, google it cookie vs jwt

Comment: Babak Yaghoobi is wrong. The ip in the token won't prevent your token from being stolen. Ip addresses can be spoofed! Same goes for hardware equipment. Cookies HAVE security when flags path, secure, sameSite and httpOnly are set. Please read this blog post that is a better answer to all your questions https://blog.hasura.io/best-practices-of-using-jwt-with-graphql/

Comment: Please note that the code is for ReactJS, best the practices can be used by any other library / framework

Comment: Thanks BabakYaghoobi for all the help. @Morselli I understand the concept successfully with secuity purpose. Thanks for the article.

Comment: @BabakYaghoobi JWT's content is readable. You must not include user's password in that.